# Need to add values into existing rows and columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called CUSTOMERS with **5 columns** and **3 rows**:
LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, ADDRESS, CITY, ORDER_PRICE
and I keep screwing it up and having to delete new rows I create because I'm unsure how to insert into the ORDER_PRICE column, values for rows 1 2 and 3.

i've tried insert into, update table clauses but i'm doing something wrong. Can anyone tell me how to insert values into rows 1, 2, & 3 or column ORDER_PRICE? ORDER_PRICE is of sata type NUMBER

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming firstname+lastname is unique:

```
update  CUSTOMERS
set     ORDER_PRICE = 4.7
where   FIRST_NAME = 'The' and LAST_NAME = 'Dude'

update  CUSTOMERS
set     ORDER_PRICE = 4.2
where   FIRST_NAME = 'Big' and LAST_NAME = 'Lebowsky'

...
```

Comment: what if i have a stock apples which qty is 50 then if i entered bill details,how can add old qty + new qty

Comment: @Anburaj_N: You'd say `set qty = qty + 12`

Answer (score 4):

To change the value of a column or columns in an existing row you should use an UPDATE statement, as in

```
UPDATE CUSTOMERS
  SET ORDER_PRICE = 123.45,
      CITY = 'San Luis Obispo'
  WHERE FIRST_NAME = 'Bob' AND
        LAST_NAME = 'Jarvis';
```

If you want to create a NEW row you'll want to use an INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS
  (LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, ADDRESS, CITY, ORDER_PRICE)
VALUES
  ('Jarvis', 'Bob', '12345 Sixth St', 'Cucamonga', '123.45');
```

Share and enjoy.